# How do I create a file, but not download it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, download

I am trying to create an image file in a web app using javascript, then make it available to retrieve with python, but not actually download it. Every solution I have found to create a file immediately downloads the file once it's created. Is there a way I can do this? And if not, is there a way I can specify the location this file downloads to?

Note: I'm running the app in a docker container, so if I could possibly store it somewhere in there, I'd prefer that.

Thank you!

Comment: You can open a save dialog which would let the user select where the image is saved to. For security purposes, I don't think applications running the browser can write anywhere they would like onto the file system. Do you have control over the webserver? If so, you could save the image from there.

Comment: I need the user to not have to see the process, because python would have caught it. The app can be run locally or on a server I have control of. I understand the reasons why this wouldn't normally happen, but basically it's being piped from one web app directly into another, and the user wouldn't have to deal with the interplay between the two.

Comment: If you have access to the node webserver, you can write a file with the `fs` package. Here's a blog post: https://stackabuse.com/writing-to-files-in-node-js/. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I was just looking into that. Thanks!